# Si tengo un método que me retorna un ArrayList, cómo hago para imprimir en otra clase ese ArrayList usando el método?

Tags: java, poo, csv, arraylist, método

Parte del código en la clase donde está el método:

```
package Clases;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListasDatos {

//LISTAS DE OBJETOS
private ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Cliente> getClientes() {
    return clientes;
}

public void anadirClientes() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    FileReader archivo = new FileReader("clientes.csv");
    BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(archivo);

    String linea;

    while ((linea = lector.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] linea2 = linea.split(",");
        clientes.add(new Cliente(linea2[0], linea2[1], linea2[2], linea2[3], linea2[4]));

    }
}
```

En la clase principal tengo un menú y cuando el usuario ingresa la opción que desea, primero se debe mostrar el listado con la información de los clientes. El código en la clase principal es este:

```
public class Tecnicentro {

//OBJETOS QUE CONTENDRA TODAS LAS LISTAS
ListasDatos datos= new ListasDatos();

//MENU DE INICIO
public void menu() throws IOException{

    boolean validar = false;

    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    while ( validar == false ) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese su usuario");
        String usuario = sc1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su contraseña");
        String contrasena = sc1.nextLine();

        Usuario user = datos.verificarUsuario(usuario, contrasena);

        //SI NO EXISTE USUARIO REINICIAR CICLO
        if ( user == null ) continue;

        switch (user.getNivel()) {
            case "admin":
                menuAdmin();
                break;
            case "tecnico":
                menuTecnico();
                break;
            case "cobranzas":
                menuCobranzas();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

//METODOS PARA AÑADIR OBJETOS A LISTAS
public void inicializarSistema() throws IOException{

    this.datos = new ListasDatos();
    datos.anadirUsuarios();
    datos.anadirClientes();
    datos.anadirProveedores();
    datos.anadirServicios();
    datos.anadirOrdenes();

}

//MENU ADMIN
public void menuAdmin(){

    boolean validar = false;
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (validar == false){

        System.out.println("MENU ADMIN");
        System.out.println("1. Administrar Clientes");
        System.out.println("2. Administrar Proveedores");
        System.out.println("3. Administrar Servicios");
        System.out.println("4. Atrás");
        System.out.println("Ingresar una opción");
        String opcion = sc2.nextLine();
        switch (opcion) {
            case "1":
               System.out.println(datos.getClientes());
               administrarClientes();
                break;
            case "2":
                administrarProveedores();
                break;
            case "3":
                administrarServicios();
                break;
            case "4":
                validar = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}    

//MÉTODO ADMINISTRAR CLIENTES
public void administrarClientes(){

    boolean validar = false;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (validar == false){
        System.out.println("1. Agregar cliente");
        System.out.println("2. Regresar al menú principal");
        System.out.println("Ingresar una opción");
        String opcion = sc.nextLine();
        switch (opcion) {
            case "1":
                agregarCliente();
                break;
            case "2":
                validar = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Si el usuario ingresa el 1 de "Administrar clientes", le debe aparecer el listado de la información de clientes.
Esto es lo que me sale al correr el programa:

```
[Clases.Cliente@7699a589, Clases.Cliente@58372a00, Clases.Cliente@4dd8dc3, Clases.Cliente@6d03e736]
```

Comment: Al hacer System.out.println(datos.getClientes()); pintas los objetos, por eso te está imprimiendo eso. haz un foreach sobre el array que te devuelve datos.getClientes() e imprime sus propiedades, no el objeto cliente

Answer (score 2):

Según el código que muestras no veo el por qué te muestra eso, aunque puedo imaginármelo.

> `[Clases.Cliente@7699a589, Clases.Cliente@58372a00, Clases.Cliente@4dd8dc3, Clases.Cliente@6d03e736]`

Esto que te muestra es porque probablemente estás recorriendo una ArrayList de manera que te haga print al resultado tal cual (Por ejemplo como si usaras un `toString()`), para evitar esto y recorrer el ArrayList usa un `Iterator`:

```
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Supongamos que tenemos esa lista definida:

```
Iterator it = clientes.Iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
Cliente cliente = it.next(); //Aqui tomamos la clase del cliente
cliente.mostrarInfo(); //Cree un método para mostrar los datos y poder usarlo aqui
}
```

De esta manera puede recorrer el ArrayList sin problemas, si aun necesita más info sobre los iterators puede ver más [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm) o [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Answer (score 2):

Solo has de añadir este metodo en la clase Cliente:

```
public String toString(){
     String datosDeCliente = "Aqui pon los datos del ciente con el formato que quieras";
     return datosDeCliente;
 }
```

En el metodo menuAdmin cuando lee el numero 1 lo primero que imprime es un arrayList que contiene clientes. Solo hace falta implementar el metodo toString en la clase Cliente para que no imprima esos simbolos.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String toString(){
         return "Acá van datos de la clase con el formato que gustes"; //ej. "Nombre: "+ nombre +", Apellido: "+apellido+ "."

    }
```

Comment: Si acompañas ese pequeño codigo con una breve explicacion tu pregunta quedaria mejor. Un saludo :)